# Stability of fixed points for a differential equation

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

> Consider the differential equation $x'=x^2-9$
>
> a. find the stability type of each fixed point

To find the fixed points, I set this equal to $0$, right? Would someone mind explaining *why* I do this? I don't really understand the concept.

So I get the fixed point as being $x=3$ and $x=-3$.

Checking the stability:

For $x=3$:
$x=2$ results in $-5$ (left)
$x=4$ results in $7$ (right)

Unstable?

For $x=-3$:
$x=-4$ is positive (left)
$x=-2$ is negative (right)

Stable?

How do I determine their stability exactly?

> b.  sketch the phase portrait on the line
>
> c. Sketch the graph of $x(t)=ϕ(t;x_0)$ in the $(t,x)$-plane for several representative initial conditions $x_0$.

Comment: You mean $x' = x^2-9$?

Comment: Fixed points are points where the solution to the differential equation is, well, fixed. That is, it doesn't move (i.e. doesn't change with respect to $t$). If it isn't moving, its derivative is zero. If its derivative $x'$ is zero, this means that $x^2 - 9$ is zero as well.

Comment: You might also say a little more about your thoughts on the other parts of this question; what have you tried, or what similar problems have you completed, and why is this one different? (or maybe you have no idea what a phase portrait is, but you should say so)

Comment: @graydad well it was x dot does that mean x'?

Comment: @MathMajor yes both are identical. I used the "prime" notation in my class but I know "dot" notation is fairly standard.

Comment: @BaronVT ok, well we just started this topic and this is the first proablem in the chapter so i haven't completed any similar problems. and eys i have no idea what a phase portrait is but i thought i would wait and work out aprt a first

Comment: @MathMajor Also, remember $x$ is a function with input $t$, so you aren't checking $x = -2$, you are checking $t = -2 \implies$ checking $x'(-2)$. Do you know how to sketch a phase portrait?

Comment: @graydad no i don't know how..i'm reading some websites online trying to figure it out now, for the stability did i get that right? and for your answer below did you mean if the left side is negative and positive to the right its unstable (in the last line)?

Comment: Whoops! Yes you are correct about my last line. The stability should be $t=3$ is unstable, $t = -3$ is unstable. Let me know if you need any help with the phase portrait.

Comment: @graydad based on the definitions and the answer submitted below, it seems that the phase portrait is just simply arrows going towards or away from the fixed points, depending on what I got for my calulcations of stability. (this is probably an oversimplification) but other than that, what do I need to do to draw the phase portrait?

Comment: That's mostly correct. Amzoti included a beautiful plot below so you can see what it looks like. I'll include a hand-drawn sketch in my answer so you know what to draw in the future

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find the fixed points, we set $x' = 0$ and solve, yielding:

$$x' = x^2 -9 = 0 \implies x_{1,2} = \pm~3$$

To test stability, you can follow [*Paul's Online Notes*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/DirectionFields.aspx#IntCurves), by picking values around the critical points and noting the sign of the derivative $x'$.

If we draw a phase line, we get (note that $+3$ is unstable and $-3$ is stable):

[image]

If we draw a direction field plot and then superimpose solution curves on it, we have (compare the two critical points to the phase line and look at each (purple) solution curve):

[image]

Note, for the solution curves (the direction field plot shows many examples), you can take several examples for different ICs, for example (just as the plot shows).

$$x' = x^2 - 9, x(0) = 1 \implies x(t) = \dfrac{6-3 e^{6 t}}{e^{6 t}+2}$$

What happens to $x(t)$ as $t$ approaches infinity? It approaches $-3$.

Answer (score 2):

Remember, $x'(t)$ tells us the rate of change of $x(t)$. You want to set it equal to zero because that indicates a point where $x(t)$ is not changing (that is to say, it is fixed). To determine stability, check values of $x'(t)$ on the left and right of your fixed points. For example, for the fixed point $t = -3$, check the value of $x'(-4)$ and $x'(-2)$. If $x'(t)$ is positive to the left of $x'(-3)$ and negative to the right of $x'(-3)$ then $t=-3$ is stable. If the left and right are the same sign, you have semi-stability. If the left side is negative while the right is positive, you have instability.

[image]

Hopefully this picture illustrates that solutions move towards $x(-3)$ and away from $x(3)$